Element does not exist in dataset when selected via selectInput
In the shiny app below I try to group by selected input but I get:
Caused by error in `all_of()`:
! Can't subset elements that don't exist.
✖ Element `abs_edu` doesn't exist.

This is my code:
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
    
# Sample data (assuming you have more columns)
Test_RShiny_Data <- structure(list(abs_edu = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1), abs_employ = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 1), abs_wash = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1), abs_health = c(1, 0, 
0, 1, 1), abs_protection = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1), abs_document = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1), ast_hhasset = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0), ast_itc = c(1, 0, 
1, 1, 1), ast_transport = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1), ast_nonessential = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 0), ast_employ = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), ast_save = c(0, 0, 
1, 0, 0), sc_safecom = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0), sc_group = c(0, 1, 1, 
1, 1), sc_safeharass = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sc_safeterror = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), sc_safehh = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ac_edu = c(3, 3, 3, 
2, 3), ac_numemploy = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), ac_supportwork = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 1), ac_tension = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), cs = c(1, 1, 1, 0.441957086324692, 
1), ge = c(0.526506841182709, -0.51858788728714, 0.526506841182709, 
-0.51858788728714, -0.51858788728714), gbv = c(0.770168602466583, 
0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583
), country = c("Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", "Moldovan", NA, "Ukrainian"
), marital = c("Seperated/divorced/widowed", "Seperated/divorced/widowed", 
"Married", "Married", "Single/Engaged"), child = c("1-3 children", 
"1-3 children", "More than 3 children", "1-3 children", "1-3 children"
), ageg = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3), res = structure(c(0.0514511360129742, 
-0.215042617390641, -0.0574834900086346, -0.0544855258954085, 
0.0261650395060347), dim = c(5L, 1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Res"), class = c("lavaan.matrix", 
"matrix")), rci = structure(c(70.7314751579487, 33.9672828176585, 
55.7033797807544, 56.1169644441105, 67.2431272937182), dim = c(5L, 
1L), dimnames = list(NULL, "Res"), class = c("lavaan.matrix", 
"matrix"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
    
# Shiny UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Select Column Names"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("vars_rci", "Choose a column:", 
                  choices = colnames(Test_RShiny_Data), 
                  multiple = FALSE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("stacked")
    )
  )
)
    
# Shiny Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  rsm_data <- reactive({
    req(input$vars_rci)
    
    d <- Test_RShiny_Data %>%
      group_by(across(all_of(input$vars_rci))) %>%
      summarise(
        abs = mean(abs_edu, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(abs_employ, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(abs_wash, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(abs_health, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(abs_protection, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(abs_document, na.rm = TRUE),
        ast = mean(ast_hhasset, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ast_itc, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ast_transport, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ast_nonessential, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ast_employ, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ast_save, na.rm = TRUE),
        sc = mean(sc_safecom, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(sc_group, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(sc_safeharass, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(sc_safeterror, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(sc_safehh, na.rm = TRUE),
        ac = mean(ac_edu, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ac_numemploy, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ac_supportwork, na.rm = TRUE) + mean(ac_tension, na.rm = TRUE)
      ) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = c(abs, ast, sc, ac), names_to = "Pillar", values_to = "Value") %>%
      group_by(across(all_of(input$vars_rci))) %>%
      mutate(Percentage = Value / sum(Value))
    
    return(d)
  })
      
  output$stacked <- renderPlot({
    req(rsm_data())
    
    ggplot(rsm_data(), aes_string(x = input$vars_rci, y = "Value", fill = "Pillar")) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      geom_text(aes(label = sprintf("%.2f", Percentage), y = Value + 0.05), 
                position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
      labs(title = paste("RSM by", input$vars_rci), x = input$vars_rci, y = "Value") +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("abs" = "skyblue", "ast" = "orange", "sc" = "green", "ac" = "red"))
   })
}
    
# Run the Shiny App
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


Session Info:
R version 4.3.3 (2024-02-29 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
    
Matrix products: default 
    
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
    
time zone: Europe/Bucharest
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] formattable_0.2.1    DT_0.32              corrplot_0.92        bslib_0.7.0         
 [5] GPArotation_2024.3-1 lubridate_1.9.3      forcats_1.0.0        stringr_1.5.1       
 [9] purrr_1.0.2          readr_2.1.5          tidyr_1.3.1          tibble_3.2.1        
[13] ggplot2_3.5.0        tidyverse_2.0.0      fmsb_0.7.6           plyr_1.8.9          
[17] readxl_1.4.3         dplyr_1.1.4          lavaan_0.6-17        psych_2.4.3         
[21] shiny_1.8.1         
    
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.4      xfun_0.45         htmlwidgets_1.6.4 lattice_0.22-5    tzdb_0.4.0       
 [6] crosstalk_1.2.1   quadprog_1.5-8    vctrs_0.6.5       tools_4.3.3       generics_0.1.3   
[11] stats4_4.3.3      parallel_4.3.3    fansi_1.0.6       pkgconfig_2.0.3   lifecycle_1.0.4  
[16] farver_2.1.2      compiler_4.3.3    textshaping_0.3.7 munsell_0.5.1     mnormt_2.1.1     
[21] httpuv_1.6.14     htmltools_0.5.8   sass_0.4.9        yaml_2.3.8        crayon_1.5.3     
[26] later_1.3.2       pillar_1.9.0      jquerylib_0.1.4   MASS_7.3-60.0.1   rsconnect_1.2.1  
[31] cachem_1.0.8      nlme_3.1-164      mime_0.12         tidyselect_1.2.1  digest_0.6.35    
[36] stringi_1.8.3     labeling_0.4.3    fastmap_1.1.1     grid_4.3.3        colorspace_2.1-0 
[41] cli_3.6.2         magrittr_2.0.3    utf8_1.2.4        pbivnorm_0.6.0    withr_3.0.0      
[46] scales_1.3.0      promises_1.2.1    timechange_0.3.0  rmarkdown_2.27    cellranger_1.1.0 
[51] ragg_1.3.0        hms_1.1.3         evaluate_0.24.0   memoise_2.0.1     knitr_1.47       
[56] rlang_1.1.3       Rcpp_1.0.12       xtable_1.8-4      glue_1.6.2        rstudioapi_0.16.0
[61] jsonlite_1.8.8    R6_2.5.1          systemfonts_1.0.6


I can't reproduce your error - the app runs fine for me. Which package versions are you using?

check my edit please

I can't replicate either. Have you tried this code in a fresh R session?

Try dplyr::summarise()

yes same error suddenly today

it worked thanks

Also, try ggplot(rsm_data(), aes(x = .data[[input$vars_rci]], y = .data[["Value"]], fill = .data[["Pillar"]])).  aes_string() has been deprecated.
